# finding last 5 minutes page views

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a kafka topic by the name of page_views and stream by the name of pageviews. Now I want to calculate last 5 minutes page viewed.I am using ksql. 
Tried with

```
SELECT after->pageview_id FROM pageviews WHERE after->pageview_id >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

and

```
SELECT AFTER ->pageview_id FROM pageviews WHERE after->pageview_id >= sysdate - 5/(24*60);
```

but not working. This is nested avro schema.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HOPPING` window to emulate sliding window in KSQL. For a hopping window you should specify the window size which in this case is `5 minutes` and an advance value which indicate how the window moves, i.e. slides (for example, every 1 second). So you can write a query like this:

```
CREATE STREAM foo AS SELECT after->pageview_id AS pv_id FROM pageviews;

CREATE TABLE bar AS SELECT pv_id, COUNT(pv_id) FROM foo WINDOW HOPPING (SIZE 5 MINUTES, ADVANCE BY 1 SECOND) GROUP BY pv_id;
```

For more information on `HOPPING WINDOW` refer to the following pages:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/syntax-reference.html#ksql-statements
- https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#hopping-time-windows